# Authentication Required error when using Google OAuth in Mailkit

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, google-oauth, mailkit

I'm trying to use Google OAuth in mailkit to send a mail from my application.

Using Google Auth .net library, I've got the access token for the user from Google. When I used the access token in mailkit to send email as below,

```
var SocketOption = SecureSocketOptions.StartTls;

await smtpClient.ConnectAsync(smtp.gmail.com, 587, SocketOption).ConfigureAwait(false);

await smtpClient.AuthenticateAsync(userid, accesstoken).ConfigureAwait(false);

await smtpClient.SendAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I got the following exception from Mailkit.

> MailKit.ServiceNotAuthenticatedException: '5.7.0 Authentication Required.
> Learn more at 5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError f23sm12136220pfa.85 - gsmtp'

**Note:** I confirmed that access token I received from Google is valid by using it with Gmail API as below.

```
var gmailService = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "App name"
            });

var gmailProfile = gmailService.Users.GetProfile("me").Execute();
string EmailAddress = gmailProfile.EmailAddress;
```

So, credential I'm using is not the problem.

Comment: Are you connecting the SMTP server or gmail api?  they are different you realize.   As far as i understand MailKit connects via the SMTP server directly it doesn't go though the Gmail api so your test is not valid.

Comment: @DaImTo I mentioned about gmail API just to confirm that my credentials are valid. I'm trying to use Mailkit SMTP to send the actual mail.

Comment: What do Oauth2 credentials have to do with SMTP server?

Comment: @DaImTo For smtpClient.AuthenticateAsync function, we usually pass user id and password. Since I'm using Google OAuth, I'll be passing OAuth userid and access token returned from Google Auth API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to authenticate via OAuth2, you need to explicitly use the OAuth2 SASL mechanism:

```
var sasl = new SaslMechanismOAuth2 (userid, accesstoken);
await smtpClient.AuthenticateAsync(sasl).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Thanks! When I tried the above, I'm receiving the following error. MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpCommandException: '5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials s15sm14043912pfe.108 - gsmtp'

Comment: In SaslMechanismOAuth2 (userid, accesstoken), userid should be the email address? For example: xyz@gmail.com?

Comment: You must be using an invalid with token somehow.

Comment: BTW, make sure you are using the right scope for SMTP access. Hint: it's `"https://mail.google.com/"` - only that scope will work. None of the others will.